# How can I make custom messages appear in the console section when people open dev tools on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I recently opened dev tools on Reddit.com and Facebook.com and both of them have custom messages displayed to developers who open the console on their site.  Reddit has an ad that recruits developers and facebook has a warning in the console section warning people not to paste in code that could result in their account getting hijacked.

How can I achieve something like this?  Is this a part of the Header or footer in HTML?

Comment: Just write to the console with `console.log()`. It will be there when someone looks at the console.

Comment: right, I'm fairly certain that they are doing something more sophisticated than that.

Comment: Why are you certain of that?

Comment: color styling, font size adjustment, possible in the console?

Comment: thanks @MarkMeyer  Your patience and explanation is very much appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasLandis, In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source of Reddit in the dev tools you will find a line that looks like this:

```
        console.log("\n                  ,d\"=≥,.,qOp,\n                 ,7'  ''²$(  )\n                ,7'      '?q$7'\n             ..,$$,.\n   ,.  .,,--***²\"\"²***--,,.  .,\n ²   ,p²''              ''²q,   ²\n:  ,7'                      '7,  :\n ' $      ,db,      ,db,      $ '\n  '$      ²$$²      ²$$²      $'    Using Reddit at work? Work for Reddit.\n  '$                          $'        https://www.reddit.com/jobs\n   '$.     .,        ,.     .$'\n    'b,     '²«»«»«»²'     ,d'\n     '²?bn,,          ,,nd?²'\n       ,7$ ''²²²²²²²²'' $7,\n     ,² ²$              $² ²,\n     $  :$              $:  $\n     $   $              $   $\n     'b  q:            :p  d'\n      '²«?$.          .$?»²'\n         'b            d'\n       ,²²'?,.      .,?'²²,\n      ²==--≥²²==--==²²≤--==²\n")
```

It's just a `console.log()` statement. You can open the snippet below and try it yourself:

```js
console.log("\n                  ,d\"=≥,.,qOp,\n                 ,7'  ''²$(  )\n                ,7'      '?q$7'\n             ..,$$,.\n   ,.  .,,--***²\"\"²***--,,.  .,\n ²   ,p²''              ''²q,   ²\n:  ,7'                      '7,  :\n ' $      ,db,      ,db,      $ '\n  '$      ²$$²      ²$$²      $'    Using Reddit at work? Work for Reddit.\n  '$                          $'        https://www.reddit.com/jobs\n   '$.     .,        ,.     .$'\n    'b,     '²«»«»«»²'     ,d'\n     '²?bn,,          ,,nd?²'\n       ,7$ ''²²²²²²²²'' $7,\n     ,² ²$              $² ²,\n     $  :$              $:  $\n     $   $              $   $\n     'b  q:            :p  d'\n      '²«?$.          .$?»²'\n         'b            d'\n       ,²²'?,.      .,?'²²,\n      ²==--≥²²==--==²²≤--==²\n")
```

You can get color in the browser's console with code like (it won't work in a SO snippet, but if you copy/paste into the browser console it will):

```
console.log('%c This is reversed! ', 'background: #ee11cc; color: #eee');
```

You can find the code for the ad by searching in the source as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the console with the console.log() command.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: My question was about how specifically Reddit.com and Facebook.com achieve their styled messages in the console

Comment: This documentation may help:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css